# Effect "AuthEffects.register$" dispatched an invalid action

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects

i've added new effect for register action and got this error: **Effect "AuthEffects.register$" dispatched an invalid action**

So, this is my effect:

```
@Effect()
register$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<Register>(AuthActionTypes.Register),
    map(action => action.payload),
    exhaustMap((register: RegisterModel) =>
      this.authService
        .register(register)
        .pipe(
          tap(status => new RegisterSuccess(status)),
          catchError(error => of(new RegisterFailure(error)))
        )
    )
);
```

this is RegisterSuccess action:

```
export class RegisterSuccess implements Action {
  readonly type = AuthActionTypes.RegisterSuccess;

  constructor(public payload: boolean) {}
}
```

it returns an boolean which says if register was successfully.
This is reducer case:

```
case AuthActionTypes.RegisterSuccess: {
        return {
            ...state,
            error: null,
            success: action.payload
        }
    }
```

Where is the problem? Effect looks like to be ok, action also, is the problem in my reducer?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tap` should be a `map` in order to return an action.

```
@Effect()
register$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<Register>(AuthActionTypes.Register),
    map(action => action.payload),
    exhaustMap((register: RegisterModel) =>
      this.authService
        .register(register)
        .pipe(
          map(status => new RegisterSuccess(status)),
          catchError(error => of(new RegisterFailure(error)))
        )
    )
);
```